# org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, openapi-generator

I'm building openAPI generator project in IntelliJ Idea (using Maven and jdk Termurin 1.8) and I got following exception:

org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip'.

My team mates are not having any problem. They are running the project without any issues.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.8:invoke (default) on project openapi-generator-gradle-plugin-mvn-wrapper: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip'. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.8:invoke (default) on project openapi-generator-gradle-plugin-mvn-wrapper: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip'.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip'.
at org.fortasoft.maven.plugin.gradle.GradleMojo.execute (GradleMojo.java:270)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.c.a (SourceFile:26)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.n.a (SourceFile:23)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.h.a (SourceFile:28)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.m.a (SourceFile:27)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.a.c (SourceFile:115)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.a.a (SourceFile:61)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.e.a (SourceFile:27)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.l.a (SourceFile:17)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.d.a (SourceFile:42)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.b.a (SourceFile:26)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.f$1.run (SourceFile:35)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute (SourceFile:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute (SourceFile:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute (SourceFile:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute (SourceFile:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute (SourceFile:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute (SourceFile:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run (SourceFile:47)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.f.a (SourceFile:31)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.d.k.a (SourceFile:65)
at com.gradle.maven.cache.extension.h.b.lambda$createProxy$0 (SourceFile:65)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.execute (Unknown Source)
at com.gradle.maven.scan.extension.internal.d.a.executeMojo (SourceFile:114)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.